# JavaEE MySQL connection: No suitable driver found

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee

I want to establish a connection to my MySQL database from my Java EE web application so I can query it from it. I added `mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar` to my `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Now when I try to establish a connection it says:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost?autoReconnect=true.

The lines in my code where the error occurs are:

```
m_url = "jdbc:mysql://" + mDatabaseHost +"?autoReconnect=true";
m_connection = DriverManager.getConnection(m_url, mDatabaseUser, mDatabasePassword);
```

User and password are correct. What might be wrong?

I tested this with Tomcat 7.0.

Comment: How are you initializing the driver?

Comment: @Dave: JDBC4 drivers autoinitialize itself by `ServiceLoader`. The Connector/J 5.1.x is a JDBC4 driver.

Comment: @BalusC Yep, it is; saw it as 5.0 somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you forgot to initialize driver.

You have to say something like the following: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` bofore connecting to DB.

Comment: This yields a ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the database name after localhost and ensure that you don't have skip-networking in the my.cnf file

**UPDATE**

Put the Connector Jar into `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`